# Android set menu items dynamically at startup

Tags: java, android, fragment, menuitem, action-menu

I need to change the title of a menu item in my action bar at startup based on a few variables which get created at the startup.
But for some reason I cant simply do that since the menu items take time to inflate maybe?
how do I get around this issue.
below is my attempt but it throws `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_fragment_action_menu, menu);
    mOptionsMenu = menu;
    mOptionsMenu.getItem(R.id.map_fragment_action_layers_0).setTitle("my title");
}
```

P.S. I am using a fragment, I also tried to set the title in `onCreateView()` method but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the method `Menu#findItem()` instead.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_fragment_action_menu, menu);
    mOptionsMenu = menu;
    mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.map_fragment_action_layers_0).setTitle("my title");
}
```

`Menu#getItem()` expects an index and not the menu item's id. For e.g, if this menu item is the first item in the menu, you would use

```
mOptionsMenu.getItem(0).setTitle("my title");
```

Comment: Thanks, findItem did the job